# Is there a more generic way of throwing a 404 than raising AR::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Everything is in the title. I'm used to writing "raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" to raise a 404 but I hope there is a more generic (and ORM agnostic) way of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can render with status 404; by default I believe this will still execute the current actions view

```
render :status => 404
```

if you want your public/404.html file to render try

```
render :file => 'public/404.html', :status => 404
```

see also http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464 'rendering a file'